# Namespace of the Entity within the modelbuilder in EF core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Interestingly, I have **two entities with the same name** from two different projects.

I'm not able to specify the **namespace of the entity** within the modelbuilder to differentiate the entities.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Namespace1.Photo>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Namespace2.Photo>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @haim770 it doesn't like the namespace syntax in that LOC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the approach that worked for me was to avoid the same name for the entity in both the projects.